# How to bind primeng p-inputswitch control in turbo table and perform get and set operations

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I have primeng turbo table which can have indefinite number of rows. I have a column "IsActive" that needs to be shown in all rows. I need to use p-inputswitch for "IsActive" column. The issue I am facing is how do I implement p-inputswitch for these many rows.

**Ideas:**
I was thinking to bind value for each column using ngModel where its name will be generated using 'isActive'+ rowid. E.g [(ngModel)] = isActive1 for first row AND [(ngModel)] = isActive2 for second row AND [(ngModel)] = isActive3 for third row and so on and reading these values in .ts file. The complexity is because of indefinite number of rows(lots of 'isActive+n:boolean' should be defined in .ts file which I do not prefer opting for.)

What is best way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the switch to the field on the item directly, like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-product>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="product.test"></p-inputSwitch>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

See [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablesections-demo-nddtvr?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Doing so will show input switch in UI but true/false value is not set. It is always showing false.

Comment: Did you change `product` and `test` to what you're using in your project?
Did you check the demo?

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I had to add [ngModelOptions]="{standalone : true}".